# laravel 5 nested routing issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

New to Laravel 5, and building a little Rest test app.  So I'm envisioning 2 different endpoints for a single controller.

```
/myApp/public/index.php/states/{state}/cities  //returns cities in a state
```

and

```
/myApp/public/index.php/states/{state}/cities/{city}  //will do somethin else
```

its a little unclear to me how to set up the routes for this.  I suppose I could have these endpoints use the same controller method, but it seems like better architecture to just route each to its own method.

So far, I've got 2 things that each individually work, but dont work together:

in routes.php

```
//route to the first endpoint
Route::resource('states.cities', 'StatesController');
//routes to the second endpoint if first is uncommented,otherwise blank page with no errors in log
Route::resource('states.cities', 'StatesController@cities');
```

And the relevant part of my controller code:

```
class StatesController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index(Request $request, $state)
    {
        //works
        $cities = States::where('state', '=', $state)->lists('name');
        echo json_encode($cities);
    }


    public function cities(Request $request, $state, $city)
    {
        echo "second request";
        echo $state;
        echo $city;
    }
    ......
```

Any one have any ideas on the proper way to handle this going forward?  Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
Route::get('states/{state}/cities', [
    'as' => 'state.cities',
    'uses' => 'StatesController@index'
]);
```

And second.

```
Route::get('states/cities/{state}/{city}', [
    'as' => 'city.of.state',
    'uses' => 'StatesController@cities'
]);
```

Note: There is no need to use `resource` route in this case. The `resource` routes creates the whole array of different routes which you really don't need. [Resource controllers](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/controllers#restful-resource-controllers)

Comment: great thanks!  small change for my usecase though, second route should be, `states/{state}/cities/{city}', but I see the concept you illustrated and was able to figure it out.  Thanks again!

Comment: just out of curiosity, though, it appears as the 'as' can really be anything you want though?  does the number of dots matter?

Comment: No not really. You can have as many dots or you may have no dot at all. Actually its just a fancy Laravel way of naming the route....which u can altogether ignore... :-)